# mdframed forces new page in the middle of a frame, solved by \clearpage. Why?

Tags: mdframed

This is somehow a poor question, as I don't have an MWE...

I have a problem with an `mdframed` environment. The environment breaks to a new page for apparently no reason. A screen shot of the effect is given below. However, I'm not able to reproduce the problem in a small MWE. I have done some research though, and the following seems to apply:

- <s>It's only a problem for this one environment.</s>  I have several equal environments in the document - the problem now appeared in another one.
- Both breaking environments are located at the beginning of a page
- Removing a block of text in front of the environment removes the break
- Adding a `\lipsum` text in front of the environment removes the break
- However, I have tried both whitespace line and `\par` in front of the environment to no effect

Anyone having any experience with this kind of behaviour? `\clearpage` before the environment solves the problem. Why? What may the `\clearpage` remove?

[image]

Comment: this is a shot in the dark.  a `\lipsum` text ordinarily ends with a `\par` (a condition that's not always obvious). is it possible that your `mdframed` environment begins in the middle of another paragraph?  if so, try putting a blank line above it and see if anything changes.

Comment: @barbarabeeton Nope, that's not it. See edit!

Comment: another suggestion -- rather drastic, i'm afraid.  what happens when you precede the environment with `\newpage` ?

Comment: Nope. But a `\clearpage` *before* the `mdframed` environment solves the problem. What?

Comment: i did mean *before* the `mdframed` environment.  so you're saying that `\newpage` and `\clearpage` behave differently?  (or are we talking in circles?)

Comment: Oups, read that too fast. `\newpage` and `\clearpage` both solves the problem.

Comment: What are you using to set the equation? `align*`?

Comment: @Werner No, in this case its `\[\]`. I've tried with `equation` as well. But I *do* have another environment with `align*` in it that behaves the exact same way.